# Created a new column using mutate, result is a column full of NAs (but this code worked for a different file I have)

Tags: r, genetics

I am using tidyr and creating a new column using mutate to sum how many 0's were returned in a different column I have. For some reason, although the new column forms, I am receiving NA's throughout the column even when I can see there should be an answer of at least one (e.g. I see a 0 in a column, but the "count" (total) column still reads N/A".

This code worked previously on a nearly identical dataset for the same type of question, can someone explain to me what is going on? A copy of my code is below.

```
Gathered <- ScottCrkMeta250918 %>% 
                gather(SNP, Genotype, 43:234)

Prefailed <- Gathered %>% 
                group_by(NMFS_DNA_ID, BOX_ID,BOX_POSITION) %>% 
                mutate(Count = sum(Genotype == 0))
```

I am trying to see how many SNPs failed, therefore I have 0s in columns where there was a failure. I am trying to tell R to tally up these zeroes (failures) and give them to me in a separate column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't share data, so this is a bit of guess. So I'm *guessing* that `Genotype` contains `NA`s. In this case, try replacing your code with

```
Prefailed <- Gathered %>% 
    group_by(NMFS_DNA_ID, BOX_ID, BOX_POSITION) %>% 
    mutate(Count = sum(Genotype == 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Here is a minimal reproducible code example to demonstrate

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- data.frame(
    Genotype = sample(c(NA, 0, 1), 10, replace = T))

df %>%
    mutate(
        Count_without_NA_removed = sum(Genotype == 0),
        Count_with_NA_removed = sum(Genotype == 0, na.rm = T))
#   Genotype Count_without_NA_removed Count_with_NA_removed
#1         0                       NA                     5
#2         0                       NA                     5
#3        NA                       NA                     5
#4        NA                       NA                     5
#5         0                       NA                     5
#6        NA                       NA                     5
#7         0                       NA                     5
#8        NA                       NA                     5
#9         1                       NA                     5
#10        0                       NA                     5
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I had tried that to override the NA, but placed it in the wrong place (only been coding for about 6 months). I also didn't know you could upload data and I will do that next time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome @MeredithJohnston, I'm glad we figured it out. Good luck with your R coding:-)